# How do you save a file to an output.txt when using tessedit_char_whitelist in tesseract?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I have managed to use

```
tesseract image.jpg output.txt
```

to read the text on an image file and save it as a text file, but now I am trying to use more specific commands with tesseract and it is trying to open the output file rather than saving into it

I am trying to use

```
tesseract image.jpg stdout -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%/-15 TextOutput
```

I have literally just started using tesseract so I may well be making a stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that if you insert a > after the specific commands it works

like this

```
tesseract image.jpg stdout -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%/-1250  > TextOutput.txt
```